# rasterio.mask.mask returning strange values

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, pandas

I am using `rasterio.mask.mask` to extract values from a raster based on a polygon feature:

```
out_img, out_transform = mask(raster, feature, all_touched=True, crop=True, nodata=-999)
```

Mostly it works except that a few of the pixels are returning a strange value of `64537`:

[image]

It looks like a `nodata` value but the type of the numerical columns of the DataFrame is `numpy.int64`, so the -999 value should be fine.

I can just filter these rows but I'd really like to understand what's happening as every pixel is important in this case.

Edit: I've checked the image histogram in QGIS and these values do not appear in the original image.